Symfony 5.8.14 : Authentification failed : user "..." does not exist Error
When I'm trying to connect to a user, I get the "Invalid Credentials" error and in the logs symfony says that the user does not exist but I checked on PHPMyAdmin and the user exist.
Here is the SecurityController :
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Attribute\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route(path: '/login', name: 'app_login')]
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', [
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error,
        ]);
    }

    #[Route(path: '/logout', name: 'app_logout')]
    public function logout(): void
    {
        throw new \LogicException('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall.');
    }
}

Here is the Login page :
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Log in!{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="flex justify-center items-center min-h-screen bg-gray-100">
        <div class="w-full max-w-md p-8 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-lg">
            {% if error %}
                <div class="mb-4 p-4 bg-red-50 border border-red-200 text-red-600 rounded-md">
                    {{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}
                </div>
            {% endif %}

            {% if app.user %}
                <div class="mb-4 text-gray-600">
                    You are logged in as <span class="font-semibold">{{ app.user.userIdentifier }}</span>,
                    <a href="{{ path('app_logout') }}" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-800">Logout</a>
                </div>
            {% endif %}

            <h1 class="text-2xl font-bold text-gray-900 mb-6 text-center">Please Sign In</h1>

            <form method="post" class="space-y-6 relative z-50">
                <div>
                    <label for="username" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" value="{{ last_username }}" name="_username" id="username" class="mt-1 block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm" autocomplete="email" required autofocus>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label for="password" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="_password" id="password" class="mt-1 block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm" autocomplete="current-password" required>
                </div>

                <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">

                <div>
                    <button type="submit" class="w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm text-sm font-medium text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
                        Sign in
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

Here is the error in logs :
[2024-08-29T10:39:55.664038+00:00] security.INFO: Authenticator failed. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\UserNotFoundException(code: 0): Username \"non@mail.com\" does not exist. at /Users/zitoune/Documents/orgaProjets/vendor/symfony/security-core/User/InMemoryUserProvider.php:101)","authenticator":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Authenticator\\FormLoginAuthenticator"} []

I tried to use ChatGPT 4.0, GitHub Copilot and BlackBox AI but they are telling me to modify the security.yaml file but when I tried to modify it, it just says "Invalid Parameters". I tried to restart from zero on another project but I get the same error.

Your error come from InMemoryUserProvider which is surprising if you expect your user to come from your database. Post your security.yaml as you may have an error with your user provider.

@DylanKAS Here is the security.yaml file :
security:
password_hashers:
Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
providers:
users_in_memory: { memory: null }
firewalls:
dev:
pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
security: false
main:
form_login:
login_path: app_login
check_path: app_login
username_parameter: _username
password_parameter: _password
enable_csrf: true

I did it it's okay !
